# How can I access the clipboard from AppleScript?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, applescript

I need to be able to send text from the clipboard to an application I'm writing (in Objective-C) via AppleScript. Obviously I need to make my application scriptable (I'm currently reading the Apple Docs about this) but is this possible/easy-to-implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need your app to retrieve data from the clipboard, you should use the [`NSPasteboard`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPasteboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.

Why do you think you need to use AppleScript?

Comment: I am trying to implement voice control for my app. I say a command word that is recognised by MacSpeech Dictate. This command launches a small app (app 1) that simply has a text field in it. I then speak the text I want sent to app 2. When I say the command "execute", I want MacSpeech to cut the text in app 1's text field and send it to an NSString object in app 2.

Comment: The reason I don't speak directly into app 2 is because app 2 doesn't have any form of GUI.

Answer (score 2):

On the AppleScript side you can use the command `set the clipboard to` to put data on the clipboard. See the [AppleScript Language Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW27).